# Mocking/Replacing interface method inside another method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I have interface with declared method

```
public interface EventAdder{
void addEvent(Event e);
}
```

now I got a class where this interface is used.

```
public class Container{

//some code here

private EventAdder ea; 

public void checkPainterState(){

//some code which I want to test inside checkPainterState

ea.addEvent(new Event(val1, val2));

}
}
```

I am using outside test class where I create `Container object`.
I want to test method `checkPainterState()` without calling `ea.addEvent()` in `checkPainterState()` method in tests. How I can mock/spy/replace this `ea object` or `ea.AddEvent` method in tests to prevent use?

Comment: Unclear. What is it that you want to test exactly? That `.addEvent()` is called? Also, unrelated: why is `ea` `public` at all in your `Container`?

Comment: I fixed code because it was a bit confusing with this names. Yes, `ea`. should be private I made small mistake when I was writing this question. I want to test `checkPainterState()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use mockito, it is as easy as to declare:

```
final EventAdder adder = mock(EventAdder.class);

// make it the adder for your container, run the method, then

verify(adder).addEvent(any(Event.class)); // or other argument matcher
```

The default behaviour of void methods when you mock it with Mockito is precisely to do nothing.